# How can I scale an element based on scroll using gsap

Tags: javascript, html, animation, gsap, scrolltrigger

I am trying to make an effect I saw on this website
https://lenis.studiofreight.com/
as you scroll down when reaching the Enter lens section the letter T scale up as you scroll.
I tried to do it but it does not work as expected.

```
<div class="mk-big sm:pt-20 h-80 sm:h-96" >
  <div class="w-4 h-4 bg-white ml-auto mr-auto mt-10"></div>
</div>
gsap.to('.mk-big div',{ scale: 100, stagger: 0.25, duration: 3, scrollTrigger: {
trigger: '.mk-big',
start: '-=300',
end: '+='+innerHeight*1.3,
markers: true,
scrub: 3,
pin : '.mk-big'}})
```

Can you please help me and thank you in advanced.